# spring batch: efficient way to query results of a stored procedure within a tasklet

Tags: sql-server, spring, stored-procedures, spring-batch, spring-jdbc

My goal is to query the results of a stored procedure (sql server) using a custom row mapper within a spring batch tasklet.

I am using Spring Boot (version 2.2.2.RELEASE) and Spring Batch (4.2.1.RELEASE).

Example:

Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE storedProcName @numbers VARCHAR(max), @day DATE
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT something, something2, something3
FROM sometable
WHERE ids in (select value from string_split(@numbers,','))
AND day = @day
```

Custom Row Mapper:

```
public class CustomRowMapper implements RowMapper<CustomObject> {
    private static final String SOMETHING = "something";
    private static final String SOMETHING2 = "something2";
    private static final String SOMETHING3 = "something3";

    @Override
    public CustomObject mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
        CustomObject customObject = new CustomObject();
        customObject.setSomething(resultSet.getString(SOMETHING));
        customObject.setSomething2(resultSet.getString(SOMETHING2));
        customObject.setSomething3(resultSet.getInt(SOMETHING3));

        return customObject;
    }
}
```

Execute Stored Procedure and query the results:

```
SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
        .withProcedureName("storedProcName")
        .returningResultSet("test", new CustomRowMapper());
Map<String, Object> out = jdbcCall.execute(parameterSource);
List<CustomObject> customObjects = (List<CustomObject>) out.get("test");
```

It works fine, but there has to be a more efficient way to do this? But i didn't found anything useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> there has to be a more efficient way to do this

Spring Batch provides the [`StoredProcedureItemReader`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/database/StoredProcedureItemReader.html) which can call a given stored procedure and iterate over its results. It also allows you to use a custom mapper as the one you defined.

According to your code snippet, you call the procedure and get a `List<CustomObject>` over which you will need to iterate at some point. So I think a chunk oriented tasklet with a `StoredProcedureItemReader<CustomObject>` is a good choice for you:

```
@Bean
public StoredProcedureItemReader<CustomObject> itemReader() {
    return new StoredProcedureItemReaderBuilder<CustomObject>()
            .procedureName("storedProcName")
            .rowMapper(new CustomRowMapper())
            // set other properties
            .build();
}
```

**Edit:** show how to return a synchronized reader

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public SynchronizedItemStreamReader<CustomObject> itemReader() {
    StoredProcedureItemReader<CustomObject> reader = new StoredProcedureItemReaderBuilder<>()
            .procedureName("storedProcName")
            .rowMapper(new CustomRowMapper())
            // set other properties
            .build();

    SynchronizedItemStreamReader<CustomObject> synchronizedReader = new SynchronizedItemStreamReader<>();
    synchronizedReader.setDelegate(reader);
    return synchronizedReader;
}
```

Comment: I've read that the StoredProcedureItemReader is not thread safe because its based on ResultSet. How do i wrap it into a SynchronizedItemStreamReader to make it thread safe?

Comment: Thank you. That worked. But i had to add @StepScope as well.